# Convert SQL query to rails Active Record query interface

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following sql query and I want to map it to a rails count query:

```
SELECT count(*), DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '-05:00')) as converted_date 
FROM video_logs 
where user_id = 19 and question_id = 96 and dashboard = 'player_question' 
GROUP BY converted_date;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rails 3:

```
VideoLog.select("count(*), DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '-05:00')) as converted_date").\
    where(:user_id => 19, :question_id => 96, :dashboard => 'player_question').\
    group('converted_date')
```

In rails 2:

```
VideoLog.all(:select => "count(*), DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '-05:00')) as converted_date",
    :conditions => {:user_id => 19, :question_id => 96, :dashboard => 'player_question'},
    :group => 'converted_date')
```

Comment: .select is not available in rails 2, i'm using rails 2.3.5 any suggestions ?